# How do I upgrade Cassandra on GKE?

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

Is there any specific documentation on the GKE Cassandra upgrade process? Especially when we update the image on yaml file, what would be the post upgrade steps? Normally, when the upgrade happens on non GKE, the stable upgrade needs to be done to complete the upgrade process. Can someone post the steps for GKE Cassandra upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way to perform a major version upgrade for Cassandra clusters running in Kubernetes because (1) it requires a new `cassandra.yaml` and (2) there is no easy method to upgrade the SSTables.

This may be solved in the coming months but just not yet. Cheers!

Comment: Its been few months but just checking, We need to upgrade our env from Apache open source version 3.11 to 4.1   which is running on Kubernetes cluster. If there is any document on this please provide here.

Looks like there are couple of approaches like adding new statefulset with new image with 4.1 version and scale up the cluster on new statefulset and once down with number of new nodes on new sts, scale down old sts which has 3.11.

Comment: How long a node with 5TB data will take to upgrade from 3.11 to 4.1.3 version? In our test DB one node is running upgradesstable since 7 days. we have 120 nodes in cluster.